# Unable to login with BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security encryption but unable to login .
My spring-security.xml is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 < beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
 <security:http auto-config="true" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" /> 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/emppreviewshow" access="ROLE_EMPLOYEE"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/login"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index"
        authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>

    <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query=
                "select username,password, enabled from USER_MASTER where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query=
                "select username,USER_ROLE from USER_ROLE where username =?  " />
                <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" >
        <constructor-arg name="strength" value="12" />
</bean>
```

My jsp form is

```
 <form name='loginForm' class="form-signin" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="post"> 

  <h2 class="form-signin-heading" style="padding-left:120px;">Login</h2>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "username" name="username" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus />
  <br>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model = "password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password" required/>      
  <br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />

  <a href="" style="padding-left:100px;">Forgot Password</a>  
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />

</form>
```

but i am unable to login.I am not even getting exception while login.Is there any setting to be done more or is there any mistake in configuration.

Comment: What do your debug logs look like? Did you try adding a debug point to BCryptPasswordEncoder?

Comment: set spring security log level to debug and try again

Comment: does it work without the bcrypt encoder?

Comment: yes without encryption it is working fine

Comment: Hash is generated and stored in database but where i have to keep debug  point because retrieving and checking will be taken care by spring-security.xml

Comment: You need to use same `passwordEncoder` when creating password hash for the user.

Comment: yes using the same one